# Flash goes off too early when using torch mode while taking pictures on HTC Desire

Tags: camera, flashlight, android

I am having some problems with the led of the rear camera of the HTC Desire.

I am developing an app that takes pictures using the [torch mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FLASH_MODE_TORCH) and it's working great with other devices (Nexus One, Galaxy S II,...) but with the desire the led goes off just before the picture is taken. I have tested others camera apps out there (["Camera Magic"](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.noclicklabs.camera&feature=search_result), "Distorted Camera") and it seems they have the exact same problem.

The code related is pretty standard (and it's working for other devices)

```
// set the torch mode in the Camera.Parameters 
String flashMode = parameters.getFlashMode();
List<String> flashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
if ((flashModes != null) && (flashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH))) {
    parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);    
}
...
...
// then just start the camera preview
mCamera.startPreview();
```

I was wondering if anybody knows what the problem might be or has experienced the same?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I am having the same problem with my HTC Desire.

One possible workaround to consider is to switch the flash mode to `FLASH_MODE_ON` just before you take the picture, then set it back to `FLASH_MODE_TORCH` afterwards.

The flash is stronger than the torch though, so the picture taken will not look the same as the preview.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have found the same problem especially on HTC phones.

I have placed a condition to use FLASH_MODE_ON instead of FLASH_MODE_TORCH

```
if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
    if (pList.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH) && (!ManufacturerName.contains("htc"))) {
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    }
    else
    if (pList.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON)) {
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
    }
}
```